# SharePoint authentication - Web api

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, windows-authentication, webapi

Goodnight,

I have a site in Sharepoint 2019 with a webpart spfx and I have a site where a web api runs with the business logic. The api has Windows authentication

From SharePoint I can connect to the web api using the following in the http request:

JavaScript code:

`this.context.spHttpClient.get('http://custom-api:1011/controller', {}, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include'
  })`

I tried with spHttpClient and httpClient

From the web api, I need to connect to sharepoint with the credentials of the current user and perform some actions, but it always generates error 401

C# code:

`var handler = new HttpClientHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true};
HttpClient = new HttpClient (handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync ($"{SiteUrl}/_api/web/SiteGroups");`

In summary I need to make the following jumps.

SharePoint SPFX => External Web Api => SharePoint api REST.

with spHttpClient the error was `{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}`

The test user is an administrator of the site collection

Thank you

Comment: Hello did you find a solution? I have the same issue but using spfx with react